# Safari keeps losing connection

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I'm trying to download CentOS' ISO from a mirror, and the download fails all times (connection lost). It fails after downloading something like 3.5 GB out of 4.5 GB.
The problem is that every time that I click on the arrow in the downloads tab it restarts from the beginning. How do I restart a download and keep the piece that I have already downloaded?

Comment: what is the link so I can try for you.

Comment: http://mi.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CentOS/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are downloading large files like this on a connection that isn't reliable you're best bet is probably to use a command line tool like `curl`.

Open a Terminal window, change directory to wherever you want to download the file (for example `cd ~/Desktop` to save to your desktop). And then type the command `curl -OC - http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso` to download the CentOS ISO image (I just picked this URL for an example, use you own as you wish).

If the download gets part of the way and stalls or dies, you can just run the same command again and it should restart from the place it left off.

The `O` in the command tells curl to use the remote filename and the `C -` tells it to continue where it stopped previously.

Please note: servers have to be set up to allow downloads to start from random positions, so if you try this and it always starts from the very beginning it could be that the server doesn't support it.

Comment: It seems like the server doesn't support ranges ("HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume"). I'll have to retry manually all times :(

Comment: Ah. Try another mirror of they have them.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Google Crome or Mozilla Firefox as it may fix the problem, because my Mac's Safari doesn't work very well for downloads but Chrome downloads well.